# How do I make links in bootstrap navbar to take space evenly along horizontal?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

My Code
https://www.codeply.com/p/6acopedTjG

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light sticky-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav mx-auto navbar-justified">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Skills</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a> 
        
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Blogs</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

.navbar{
    background-color: #e3fdfd;
}

.navbar-justified {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  float: none;
}
```

[This is what my output looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2zV9.png)

This is what I want my output to look like

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0qp8.png)

Comment: Please put the code in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

Add `width: 100%;` to your CSS class `.navbar-justified`

Answer (score 0):

add this class to nav ul `"navbar-nav w-100 justify-content-between"`

Comment: One line answers without details relevant to the issue or a sample of code are not very useful and prone to deletion. Try to be more thorough in your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any extra CSS to do this. Just use `nav-fill` and `w-100`...

https://codeply.com/p/3vHSPErTIQ

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light sticky-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
      <div class="navbar-nav mx-auto nav-fill w-100">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Skills</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a> 
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Blogs</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```